# Delphi UTF8ToAnsi failure

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

When I use UTF8ToAnsi on this string, the result is empty.  Any idea why that might be?

msgid "2. Broughton, PMG. ^iJournal of Automatic Chemistry.^n ^lVol 6. No 2. (April – June 1984) pp 94-95."

This demonstrates the problem:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.Text :=
  '<<' +
  UTF8ToANSI('msgid "2. Broughton, PMG. ^iJournal of Automatic Chemistry.^n^lVol 6. No 2. (April – June 1984) pp 94-95."') +
  '>>';
end;
```

which produces

"<<>>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails because what you pass is not UTF-8 encoded. What you pass this function is actually ANSI encoded. When `Utf8Decode` receives that text, it attempts to decode it and when it encounters the malformed bytes, bytes that are not UTF-8, it bails out and returns the empty string.

The problem character is the dash in *April – June 1984* which is an n-dash. In ANSI that is encoded as `#150`. When you attempt to interpret that as UTF-8, that `#150` is not a single byte encoding of a character, and is also invalid as the first byte of a multi-byte sequence. Hence the failure.

To solve your actual problem, you'll need to work out why you have data that is not UTF-8 in a place where you expect UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

`Utf8ToAnsi` returns an empty string if the input isn't valid UTF-8 (such as having an incomplete multibyte character or a malformed trailing byte). You can debug your program to discover what your string really contains. You evidently have a problem in the way you obtain your input string. Perhaps you're misinterpreting UTF-8, or perhaps you never really had UTF-8 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The dash that you use between April – June is not valid UTF8. So it cannot be decoded correctly. This is not immediately visible, but the symbol that you used here is not a normal minus, but a different character.

Comment: That was it.  Excel was converting "regular" characters into other characters.  Thank you for such a keen eye!